# Changed image does not display

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping

So I want to make an 8ball in three.js I have this setting

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var width  = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, width / height, 0.01, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 1.5;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
light.position.set( 5, 3, 5 );
scene.add( light );

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.5, 32, 32 );
THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = '';
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs0yG.jpg',
    function ( texture ) {
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
            map: texture,
          specular: new THREE.Color('grey')
         } );
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( sphere );
    },
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
    },
    // Function called when download errors
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( 'An error happened', xhr );
    }
);

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( sphere );


function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
render();
```

Now that works:

```
// ressource url
'https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCE9Z.jpg'
```

but an image with exactly the same size, format etc. fails to display:

```
// ressource url
'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs0yG.jpg'
```

working img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCE9Z.jpg
not working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs0yG.jpg
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: used .load to print out errors. Got:
`An error happened error { target: <img>, isTrusted: true, currentTarget: <img>, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, defaultPrevented: false, timeStamp: 1466344211566915, originalTarget: <img>, explicitOriginalTarget: <img>, NONE: 0 }`

Comment: You should use the `onLoad` callback method for loading/applying textures...

Comment: thanks, but still the same problem, working with 3tU4Vig.jpg but not with CkFSjjv.jpg. When logging out the error I get:

error { target: <img>, isTrusted: true, currentTarget: <img>, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, defaultPrevented: false, timeStamp: 1466343806725997, originalTarget: <img>, explicitOriginalTarget: <img>, NONE: 0 }